# VirtualBoxのネットワーク設定

Tags: centos, virtualbox

ホストOS：Windows7
ゲストOS:CentOS6.5（テスト環境）
VirtualBox: 5.0.6

■ゲスト側ミドルウェア                 
httpd   
mysql-server　                   
php                 
php-mbstring                    
php-mysql                   
php-xml
Apache
Perl

要件：
ゲスト側のwebサーバ上でPHP,PERL(cgi)のプログラムが動かせる。
ホストPC及びLAN等からつながった他のPCからもゲストPCにアクセスできる。

現状
・ゲストアダプター１：NAT
・ゲストアダプター２：ホストオンリー
・ホストOSからゲストOS(10.0.2.15)へpingが通らない。
・ゲストOS(10.0.2.15)からホストOSへpingが通る。

ホスト側ネットワーク情報
[image: ホスト側ネットワーク情報]

ゲスト側ネットワーク情報
[image: ゲスト側ネットワーク情報]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

質問1：どのようにすれば、ホストOSからゲストOS(10.0.2.15)へpingが通る。
質問2：ゲストOSのIPアドレス(10.0.2.15)を固定IPに変更する方法

ご教示をよろしくお願いします。

Comment: CentOSのバージョンはいくつですか。
GUI環境かCUI環境かどちらでしょうか。
非仮想環境での設定方法はわかるのでしょうか。
Virtual Boxの設定でネットワークアダプタの割り当ては何になっていますか(ブリッジアダプター、NAT、etc.)。
設定すべき情報(IPアドレス、デフォルトゲートウェイ、DNSサーバ、etc.)は何にするか決められていますか。またはどうやって決めるor調べるかわかっていますか。
質問を編集して情報を追記してください

Comment: VirtualBoxで構築したCentOSゲストへ、ホストPCからだけではなく、LAN等からつながった他のPCからもアクセスさせたいかどうかでも設定すべき項目が変わってきます。実現したい要件をもう少し詳細に明記してください。

Comment: 質問3のapache等の設定についてはVirtualBoxとは独立した話なので、必要に応じて別の質問として投稿してください。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. 基本方針

LANの他のPCからもゲストPCへアクセスさせたいということであれば、ゲストPC側のネットワーク設定で **ブリッジアダプター** を選択するようにします。

NATアダプターはそのままでは外部からの接続はできません。ホストオンリーアダプターもその名が示すとおり外部からの接続はできません。NATアダプターにポートフォワーディングの設定をする手もありますが、標準的でないポートでのアクセスを強いられるので、かえって面倒だと思います。

### 2. VirtualBoxの設定

ゲストboxのネットワーク設定は次のようにします。

- アダプター1：割り当て「ブリッジアダプター」

もちろん、ネットワークアダプターの有効化およびケーブル接続にチェックを入れておいてください。これ以外の設定はデフォルト値で良いでしょう。
アダプター2以降は無効化しておいたほうがトラブルのもとが減ります。

### 3. ゲストCentOSの設定

[NetworkManager](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-JP/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-NetworkManager.html) が有効化されているなら、前項の VirtualBox ネットワーク設定を行ってゲストPCを再起動するだけで自動的にIPアドレスが振られて有効になる可能性があります。

```
$ service network status
設定されたデバイス:
lo eth0
現在活動中のデバイス:
lo eth0
```

上記コマンドの結果で eth0 が活動中になっていれば

```
$ ip addr
```

で eth0 に割り当てられているIPアドレスを確認してみてください。

IPアドレスを固定するため、次にネットワーク設定ファイルを手で修正します。

#### ネットワーク設定ファイルを修正する

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts の下に ifcfg-eth0 というファイルがあるはずです。なければ新しく作ります。設定ファイルの詳しいパラメータについては [9.2 インターフェース設定ファイル Red Hat Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-JP/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html) を参照してください。
最低限、以下のような設定が必要になるはずです。

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=192.168.3.200
PREFIX=24
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

- `IPADDR`には、ゲストPCに固定で割り当てたいIPアドレスを指定します。ホストPCやLAN上の他のPCとは異なる値を設定してください。
  提示されているホスト側ネットワーク情報を見る限り、ホストが 192.168.3.0/24 に接続されているようですので、同じネットワークセグメントに属するようにするのが良いものと思われます。
- `BOOTPROTO`は`none`にすることで動的なIPアドレス割り当てがされないようになります。
- `NM_CONTROLLED`は`no`にしておくことでNetworkManagerによる自動設定対象から外れるようになります。

### 4. ホストWindowsの設定

他のPCからゲストCentOSに割り当てたIPアドレスへの接続が、ホストWindowsのファイアーウォールでせき止められないように、Windows側の設定が必要になる可能性があります。ここの説明は割愛します。

### 5. その他

ゲストCentOS側にもファイアーウォール等の設定がされているなら、それを解除する必要があるでしょう。そのあたりの設定はもはやVirtualBoxとは独立した話なので、必要ならば新しい質問を起こしてください。

### 6. 参考情報

- [[VirtualBox] ネットワーキング構成を理解して選択する : C-through the Mac](http://c-through.blogto.jp/archives/14539119.html)
- [ネットワーク設定 | VirtualBox Mania](http://vboxmania.net/node/47)

Comment: ご回答いただきまして、ありがとうございます。 アドバイス通り (1)ゲストアダプター1の割り当てを「ブリッジアダプター」に変更 (2)/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 の修正 ホストOSからゲストOS(192.168.3.200)へpingが通るようになりました。 –

Comment: @nice 解決したのであれば回答に承認をしてください [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか? - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)